# Laravel LeftJoin Multiple queries with similer name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to show role name(roles table) in admin list(admins table). I work with `leftJoin` query:

```
   $data = Admin::select('admins.*', 'roles.name')
        ->leftJoin('model_has_roles', 'model_has_roles.model_id', '=', 'admins.id')
        ->leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'model_has_roles.role_id')
        ->get();
```

In Action `print_r($data)` I see This output:

```
(
[id] => 1
[name] => administrator
[email] => m@m.com
[password] => $2y$10$7/HMHGIPIJ6FiNBLy.BynurEhcsrbWkbc4wFREN9qjAFGNqSdaFTS
[remember_token] => 
[created_at] => 2020-02-11 10:46:45
[updated_at] => 2020-02-11 10:46:45
[sex] => 
[dob] => 
[mobile] => 
[phone] => 
[address] => 
[street] => 
[city] => 
[district] => 
[state] => 
[country] => 
[photo] => 
[web] => 
[status] => New
[upload_folder] => 
[deleted_at] => 
)
```

This Work But I can't See `admin name` in list! In Output `roles name` replace with `admin name`.(`[name] => administrator`).

How do can i fix this problem and show all value from `admins table` + name of `roles table`?!

Comment: Have you tried Aliasing your roles.name? for e.g
$data = Admin::select('admins.*', 'roles.name as RoleName')

Comment: @Sehdev: Oh thanks. please add to answer

Comment: Welcome. I have already added. Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias your `roles.name` as below

> Change

```
$data = Admin::select('admins.*', 'roles.name')
```

> to

```
$data = Admin::select('admins.*', 'roles.name as RoleName')
```